# What is a good app for tracking, sharing plans, and creating visualizations of travel?

Tags: online-resources

I'm a long time [Dopplr user](http://dopplr.com/traveller/johndbritton) and I really love the travel visualizations that they make available. Since they were [acquired by Nokia](http://blog.dopplr.com/2009/09/28/nokia-acquires-dopplr/) all development has stopped and they've stopped issuing the excellent [annual reports](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dopplr/3198685033/lightbox/).

My question is, are there any good replacement web/app services that provide the same (or better) quality visuals and user experience, and are actively developed?

For the unfamiliar, Dopplr is an application that can be used to track and share travel plans.

Comment: Err, John - unless I'm missing something, are you sure this is meant to be on Travel?

Comment: Yes, Dopplr is used for keeping track of travel.

Comment: OK, it's borderline, but I made a couple of edits to help.  Feel free to adjust if I've accidentally changed your intent.

Comment: Maybe better to reframe the question as "app to track and share travel plans and visualizations" and include Dopplr as an example in the question. Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, the more actively-travel-related you can make it, the better.

Comment: Duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6594/is-there-any-travel-management-software-webportal-avaialble ?

Comment: Similar subjects, although this has more detailed requirements (visualizations) and is asking about a replacement.

Comment: Hmm stupid site, I can't register an account

Comment: If you're specifically looking for an online app as tagged, this question might better suit the [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tripit](http://tripit.com) is most people's pick for travel planning and sharing these days, its main selling point being the ability to digest flight and hotel reservations automatically, although it doesn't have much in the way of visualization capabilities.  However, it does have an API supported by a lot of third-party apps, so I can turns my TripIt plans into eg. flight maps in [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org), which supports [complete network maps](http://openflights.org/user/jpatokal) as well as [individual trip maps](http://openflights.org/trip/2).  And for extra hipster points, you can even export from OpenFlights to Google Earth!

[image]

Comment: My problem with tripit is that it becomes much less functional when it's not able to abstract your journey from booking confirmations, quite typical when using more obscure (cheap) airlines. Trips with multiple stops, also, are a bit of a hassle for tripit.

Comment: TripIt doesn't meet my needs, as it is mostly geared towards bookings and managing logistics. I'm more interested in logging my history and plans for all types of travel. Dopplr is the closest to what I'm looking for, but it too has limitations in that it assumes you live in one place and the interface to manage your schedule is very cumbersome.

Comment: @johndbritton You may want to take a look at this other post for mapping your travels: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6471/how-to-generate-a-travel-map/